# How can i get the minimum value in json- array using FOREACH?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

```
 var arr8 = [ { name : "Avi", grades : [90,76,99]},
{ name : "Dana", grades : [72,54]},
{ name : "Ron", grades : [92,66,67,79]} ]
```

this is a json of students and their grades, i want to print the minimum grade with his name only using FOREACH & lambda expressions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Even after your edit, it isn't clear if you want to print the minimum grade of each student, or only the student with the smallest grade overall.

Comment: i wanted to print the smallest grade and his name overall, in console .log must be - 54, dana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr8 = [
  { name : "Avi", grades : [90,76,99]},
  { name : "Dana", grades : [72,54]},
  { name : "Ron", grades : [92,66,67,79]}
];
let min = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

arr8.forEach(v => {
  if (min > Math.min(...v.grades))
    min = Math.min(...v.grades);
});

console.log(min);
```

Comment: this is amazing , thank you ! but what is (...v.grades) ?

Comment: So, basically `v` is single object from `arr8` and that `...` is spread operator.You can read it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) about it.

Comment: yea got it , is it possible to get than minimum without using math.min ?